# python multi open same port, is it ok?

Tags: python, pyserial

I use pySerial package. And I want to build two object for opening one same port: one for read and another for write. But I don't know whether the package support it or not. Can anyone answer?

Comment: No, that's not going to work; serial ports are usually exclusive. Why wouldn't you use the same object, as intended?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I test the one port at same time. It is ok.